# Sorting array of chars without using built-in sort()?

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following code:

```java
String input5 = "A2B3C1";
char[] lst5 = input5.toCharArray();
  
for (int i = 0; i < lst5.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < lst5.length; j++) {
        if ((Character.isDigit(lst5[i]) && Character.isDigit(lst5[j]) && lst5[i] > lst5[j]) || 
                (!Character.isDigit(lst5[i]) && !Character.isDigit(lst5[j]) && lst5[i] > lst5[j]) || 
                (lst5[i] < lst5[j] && (Character.isDigit(lst5[i])))) {
            char tmp = lst5[i];
            lst5[i] = lst5[j];
            lst5[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

}
System.out.println(lst5);
```

What I expected: "ABC123"
But I got: "ABC132"

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Change the condition to `if (Character.isDigit(lst5[i]) != Character.isDigit(lst5[j]) ? Character.isDigit(lst5[i]) : lst5[i] > lst5[j])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first for loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lst5.length-2; i++)
```

To more directly answer your question, the expression

```
(!Character.isDigit(lst5[i]) && !Character.isDigit(lst5[j]) && lst5[i] > lst5[j])
```

falls through by evaluating to false when both characters are already-sorted digits.  The next expression `(lst5[i] < lst5[j] && (Character.isDigit(lst5[i]))` is treated as though there's certainty that the characters are neither both digits nor both non-digits, which is a fallacy as they could also reach that third expression when already in sorted order.